# How to alphabetically order the contacts in an address book?

Tags: java

Can anyone help me?
I have a method as part of a larger project that manages a contact book.

I need to use a `String`, so no arrays.
I would like to use `compareTo` if possible.

The description is:

This method insert a **contact line** (exemple of a contact line:

6|cori|ben|benben@hotmail.com|4502334565 ) in a given notebook. The contact line need to be ordered alphabetically by last name.

This method does not verify dublicates.

parameter book the book where we want to introduce contact line(from the parameters)

We suppose non null the book, but is empty from beginning.

If non empty, it is formed in this way:

```
/*
       3|Crevier|Simon|simon@gmail.com|5145678988 (contact line)
       1|Douglas|Sylvie|nothing|4507461234
       2|Dumoulin|Fred|fredd@yahoo.ca|nothing
       4|Girard|Myriam|nothing|nothing

*/
```

parameters contactLine the contact to format on one line witch need to be added to the book

We assume that the contact line in non null, non empty and well formated(like in the exemple)

A new string of a new book after the insertion. The new returned book need to be well formated.

This method need to use another method : findLastNameContact() from the same class (method get the last name from the contact line ex. of line : 3|Crevier|Simon|simon@gmail.com|5145678988) => Crevier is tha last name.

We need to ignore the case.

```
/*
----------------------------------------------

METHOD IF CONTACT IS INSERTED IN THE BOOK 
----------------------------------------------
Insert 1|crook|hubert|hubcrook@gmail.com|4502765009 in the empty book... ERROR

Expected:
1|crook|hubert|hubcrook@gmail.com|4502765009

Have found:



Instert 2|aubre|Camille|aucun|5149098778... ERROR

Expected:

2|Aubre|Camille|aucun|5149098778

1|crook|hubert|hubcrook@gmail.com|4502765009

Have found:

1|crook|hubert|hubcrook@gmail.com|45027650092|aubre|Camille|aucun|5149098778

1|crook|hubert|hubcrook@gmail.com|4502765009

Instert 3|charland|Marc|mcrook@yahoo.ca|nothing... ERROR - 
NoSuchElementException unexpected.

Instert 4|mason|Isabelle|aucun|aucun... ERROR - NoSuchElementException unexpected.

Insert 5|fortin|Bruno|brunofortin@hotmail.com|5142768898... ERROR - NoSuchElementException unexpected.

Insert 6|ZHE|Xang|zzz@hotmail.com|4598765423... ERROR - NoSuchElementException unexpected.

Insert 7|morier|Dominic|doum@videotron.ca|4598765423... ERROR

Expected:

    2|Aubre|Camille|aucun|5149098778

    3|CHaRland|Marc|mcrook@yahoo.ca|aucun

    1|crook|hubert|hubcrook@gmail.com|4502765009

    5|Fortin|Bruno|brunofortin@hotmail.com|5142768898

    4|Mason|Isabelle|aucun|aucun

    7|Morier|Dominic|doum@videotron.ca|4598765423

    6|ZHE|Xang|zzz@hotmail.com|4598765423

    Have found  :

    2|Aubre|Camille|nothing|5149098778

    3|CHaRland|Marc|mcrook@yahoo.ca|nothing

    1|crook|hubert|hubcrook@gmail.com|4502765009

    5|Fortin|Bruno|brunofortin@hotmail.com|5142768898

    4|Mason|Isabelle|nothing|nothing
    6|ZHE|Xang|zzz@hotmail.com|45987654237|morier|Dominic|doum@videotron.ca|4598765423
    nothing

    6|ZHE|Xang|zzz@hotmail.com|4598765423


Insertion 8|alban|Roger|Roger@gmail.com|5143677788... ERROR - NoSuchElementException unexpected.

*/
public static String InsertThisContactInTheBook
    (String book, String contactLine) {


        String lastNameContact;
        String id, lastName, givenName, email, phone;
        String newBook = "";

        lastNameContact= findLastNameContact(contactLine);//contact line is from outside, also the findLastNameContact, witch is extraxting la last name from contact line

     //6|cori|ben|benben@hotmail.com|4502334565| (example of contact line)

        StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(book, "|");

        // newBook = book+ contactLine;

        while (tokens.hasMoreTokens()){
            id = tokens.nextToken();
            lastName = tokens.nextToken();
            givenName = tokens.nextToken();
            email= tokens.nextToken();
            phone= tokens.nextToken();

            if (lastName.compareToIgnoreCase(lastNameContact) > 0) {
                newBook = book + contactLine +  "\n" + id + "|" + lastName + "|" + givenName + "|" + email+ "|" + phone+ "\n";
            }
        }
        return newBook;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry it was easier to ask in French.I did not know that the questions are addressed only in English. I need to sort in alphabetically order the contacts  in a notebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this homework? If it is, you should let us know.

**First**, it seems to me that you're using two different kinds of delimiters inside `book`: the `|` delimiter that separates data fields within each `contactLine`, and the `\n` newline delimiter that you are using to separate individual `contactLine`s within `book`.

See this section of your code:

```java
if (lastName.compareToIgnoreCase(lastNameContact) > 0) {
    newBook = book + contactLine +  "\n" + id + "|" + lastName + "|" + givenName + "|" + email+ "|" + phone+ "\n";
}
```

Because of this, your `StringTokenizer`, which is delimiting on `|`, will parse `book` as if it was formatted like this:

```
6|ZHE|Xang|zzz@hotmail.com|45987654237|morier|Dominic|doum@videotron.ca|459876542|nothing
```

When actually the two contactLines should be:

```
6|ZHE|Xang|zzz@hotmail.com|4598765423
7|morier|Dominic|doum@videotron.ca|459876542|nothing
```

Note that there is a missing `|` delimiter between the two `contactLines`. Therefore, instead of the `StringTokenizer` recognizing 5+6= 11 tokens, it will tokenize `book` into 10 tokens, treating `45987654237` as 1 token instead of 2 separate tokens, `4598765423` and `7`.

**Second**, there is another problem with your `contactLine` entries from the output you pasted above. In the example I quoted immediately above, with "ZHE Xang" and "morier Dominic", the two lines contain different tokens. ZHE Xang's `contactLine` contains 5 tokens while morier Dominic's contains 6. Because of this, your `while` loop above won't work reliably - it is expecting all `contactLines` to have 5 tokens but some apparently have 6.

I am referencing this part of your code:

```
while (tokens.hasMoreTokens()){
    id = tokens.nextToken();
    lastName = tokens.nextToken();
    givenName = tokens.nextToken();
    email= tokens.nextToken();
    phone= tokens.nextToken();
```

---

I think the end result of both of these issues is actually the same problem: it makes the code block within your `while` loop unreliable. Whether it's because you're using two delimiters but only tokenizing on one, or whether it's because some `contactLines` have 6 tokens, the end result is that your algorithm is assuming some multiple of 5 tokens all the time, but in reality it is some combination of 5, 6, and 9 that ends up not being a clean multiple of 5.

I also have a couple more questions for you (maybe this is better put into a comment to your original post). Just food for thought.

1. Why can't you use anything other that `String`s?
2. Why are you using a static method instead of a class method (e.g. `book.insertContact(contact);`)?

Comment: Yes, you're right is a small part of a homework, but i can't figure out what to do it. I see the problem but i can fix it.  I want to use strings because i have learned up to them. I make smaller methods that i will use for larger project. This method is one of them. As you noticed this method call another method : findLastNameContact(contactLine) -> which extract the last name from the contact line. Thx for your opinion.

Comment: It would be much easier if you could use a different data structure that was more suited to the task, for example, a [Vector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) or an [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). This will avoid the first problem I pointed out (using `\n` to delimit different `contactLines`) and will also probably be much faster. Did you have another question? Did my answer help you?

Comment: Unfortunately can not use arrays or vector for this project. I have to solve the problem with the knowledge that i have until now. You helped me to see where is the problem. Another question for now i don't have, so thank you very much for your help. I appreciate that.

Comment: You are most welcome @NataliaAndronic. If my answer was helpful, please feel free to mark it as the accepted answer, and to vote it up! Hope the rest of your assignments go smoothly.

Comment: Tell me please how to do that because i'm new on this site. Thx!

Comment: Next to the answer I gave, you have the option of marking my answer as the "accepted answer" to your question, meaning, the green check mark/tick will appear.

Comment: done ;) I accepted your answer. thx!